# Planet Data API 403 Error

Tags: authentication, planet

I recently discovered the Planet API and have been working through the planet_data_api_introduction Jupyter notebook found here:

https://github.com/planetlabs/notebooks/blob/master/jupyter-notebooks/data-api-tutorials/planet_data_api_introduction.ipynb.

Within the Activating Assets section, I receive an HTTP 403 status code.

How come I get access forbidden code when I have an API key?

Answer (score 1):

There were intermittent API issues with an upstream provider recently that were resulting in 403 errors (https://status.planet.com will have updates). It could be that it was something else, but my guess is that this was the cause and that it will work if you try again now.